# How to get twitter users screen-name or UserId from a specific geolocations?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get tweets from specific geo-location, so i used tweepy (api.search) method. I am successfully getting tweets from the specific geo location. but I am not getting screen name or userid. I am expecting that show_user when True will return me the screen name, who is posting that tweet. but i am not getting any screen name. so please tell me the solution how can i get the screen name who is posting that tweet by given geo location. Using tweepy.

```
public_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, rpp=100, 
geocode="44.269493,63.341332,5km",since="2018-05-01",show_user = 
"True",tweet_mode="extended").items()
```

Comment: did you try `screen_name=userid` ?

Comment: When i run this script i am not getting any screen name or id, What i am getting is only tweets. so how can i do screen_name = userid?

Comment: `tweepy.Cursor(api.search, rpp=100, 
geocode="44.269493,63.341332,5km",since="2018-05-01",show_user = 
True,tweet_mode="extended", screen_name=userid).items()` I also removed quotes around `True` for `show_user`

Comment: getting this error
NameError: name 'userid' is not defined

Comment: and if you put quotes around `userid` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rpp is deprecated, use "count" instead (see https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html).

This works with "100km" ("5km" returned no result).

```
consumer_key = '***'
consumer_secret = '***'
access_token = '***'
access_token_secret = '***'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

tweets = api.search(count=100,geocode="44.269493,63.341332,5km",since="2018-05-01")
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.user.id_str, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text)
```